# Django-nonrel and GAE - Error - Unexpected attribute 'builtins'

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to run [django-testapp](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine) from allbuttonpressed which uses Django-nonrel.

When I run manage.py from django-testapp it gives me an error saying that

```
C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp>manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\settings.py", line 4, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\djangoappengine\settings_base.py", line 6, in <module>
    setup_env()
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 64, in setup_env
    setup_project()
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\djangoappengine\boot.py", line 114, in setup_project
    from .utils import have_appserver, on_production_server
  File "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\djangoappengine\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    appconfig, unused = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(PROJECT_DIR, {})
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3440, in LoadAppConfig
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3295, in ReadAppConfig
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 444, in LoadSingleAppInfo
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 218, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 169, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute 'builtins' for object of type <class 'google.appengine.api.appinfo.AppInfoExternal'>.
  in "C:\Projects\Goog\django-testapp\app.yaml", line 7, column 1
```

I'm using latest 1.4 GAE SDK

Anyone knows if this is an issue with the Django-nonrel or something specific to my setup.

app.yaml file:

```
application: ctst
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

builtins:
- remote_api: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine/deferred/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

Comment: Do you get any output besides that line?

Comment: http://www.vpaste.net/DdUmB Pasted the complete error message

Comment: I've inlined the stacktrace and app.yaml. Please read the formatting docks for Stack Overflow - it's not hard.

Comment: Cool thanks. It was easier to just paste it on the bin then putting some extra effort. Next time I'll remember to inline it so it's easier for people answering the question not me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your app.yaml file. Try to reset it and run application.

Comment: Your app.yaml is ok and I don't understand why AppEngine refuses to parse it. Ensure that you are using latest SDK, reset app.yaml and try to delete section "builtins".

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using the latest SDK. Possibly you have multiple SDKs installed, and Django is using a different one. Make sure you update the one in `D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine` to the latest version.

Comment: I was using the latest SDK. Not sure what was wrong so I deleted everything and started again and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a file called index.yalm and other app.yalm, try delete index.yalm and test it. I have same problem and I've resolved.